# MVC Pair Checkbox with Text Input Field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking to have something like the following:

```
@foreach(var option in ViewBag.OptionsAvailable)
{
        //the 'option' variable will be used in these fields, of course
        <input type='checkbox' name='thingToUse' />
        <input type='text' name='textToSaveForThing' />
}
```

`ViewBag.OptionsAvailable` can be of variable length. **I would like to take one of these options and add it to `Model.Options` with the saved value IF its checkbox is selected.** The idea here is that, on the `HttpPost` controller method, I want to only acknowledge/save the value in the textbox if its corresponding checkbox is selected. What's the best way to approach this?

I've come across [this explanation](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) of binding to a list, but I'm not sure how to evolve upon that to create what I want.

Comment: How is the `option` variable used?

Comment: Updated question, see code change and bolded explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by creating a view model to represent what you want to display/edit

```
public class OptionVM
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
  public string Answer { get; set; }
  .... // other properties 
}
```

Then in the controller, initialize a collection of your view model and pass it to the view

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
  List<OptionVM> model = new List<OptionVM>();
  .... // populate it
  return View(model);
}
```

and the view

```
@model List<yourAssembly.OptionVM>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    <label>
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected)
      <span>@Model[i].Text</span>
    </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Answer)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].Answer)
  }
  <input type="submit" ... />
}
```

and submit to

```
public ActionResult Edit(List<OptionVM> model)
{
  // for example, get the answers where the checkbox has been selected
  var selectedAnswers = model.Where(m => m.IsSelected).Select(m => m.Answer);
}
```

and you could enhance this by using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` or similar validation attribute applied to the `Answer` property to ensure the textbox has a value if the corresponding checkbox is checked

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have two inputs. You can use the "value" attribute of the checkboxes, and store that information. Also, in your controller, you can simply add a parameter with the same name as your input.

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (string option in ViewBag.OptionsAvailable)
    {
        <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxes' value="@option" />
        @option <!-- text to display -->
    }
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult GetCar()
{
    ViewBag.OptionsAvailable = new List<string>
    {
        "Red",
        "Yellow",
        "Blue"
    };
    return View(new Car());
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult PostCar(string[] checkboxes)
{
    Car car = new Car
    {
        ColorsSelected = new List<string>()
    };

    foreach (string value in checkboxes)
    {
        car.ColorsSelected.Add(value);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Suppose I need to use whatever specific value is set in the textbox, however. Wouldn't I need the second field then? How can I set the checkbox's value if it's to be inserted in that checkbox?

Comment: What's the point of having textboxes to fill if you're only going to send a few? I think you're looking for another type of input.

Comment: What do you mean a few? It's technically a date field, but the input will be text.

Comment: Why don't you post the real problem instead of a superset of it? :) I'll be able to help then.